# Pasar información de csv a dataframe en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Hola quiero abrir la información de un archivo .csv a DataFrame en Python.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv("MINIMOS.txt",header=0,delim_whitespace=True)
```

Quiero hacer una resta de dos columnas de estos datos, los tengo como .csv

```
   Fecha         tiempo1   tiempo2    tiempo3    tiempo4    tiempo5  Anochecer    media1   media2    media3
 2007-01-01    9.83        12.32        13.95        15.35        16.45        3.65        43.98        46.01        45.77    
 2007-01-02    9.91        12.58        14.08        15.32        16.38        3.73        43.11        46.84        46.98    
 2007-01-03    10.57        12.50        14.15        15.47        16.45        3.73        NaN          NaN          NaN 
 2007-01-04    9.91        12.47        14.15        15.43        16.43        3.70        41.98        44.70        44.03    
 2007-01-05    9.85        12.50        14.13        15.42        16.43        3.61        41.21        44.05        45.26    
 2007-01-06    10.12        12.68        14.12        15.33        16.40        3.66        41.36        43.94        43.31    
 2007-01-07    9.93        12.38        13.95        15.38        16.42        3.65        41.48        43.36        44.10
```

Alguna ayuda.

Comment: Hola Rocker, el código es correcto, falta información esencial en la pregunta ¿cuál es el problema o error? ¿Cómo es la estructura del csv? Si agregas algunas de las filas iniciales del csv sería de gran ayuda....

Comment: @FJSevilla, por que cuando uso tu ejemplo df['Age'] = df['numeros'] - df['valores'].shift(-1) no me compila.?

Comment: El otro ejemplo fue creando el dataframe con unas listas pero ahora quiero abrirlo un archivo .txt con datos como .csv para selecionar las filas y no puedo.

Comment: Si no muestras el error ni la estructura del csv poco vamos a poder ayudar, por favor edita la pregunta y agregala. Posiblemente estás parseando mal el csv (separadores, caracteres de acotado, etc) o simplemente no es un csv válido... pero como comento puede haber mil razones.

Comment: ya edite la pregunta

Comment: la resta puede ser de dos columnas al azar

Comment: Con el fragmento de csv que has agregado el código funciona perfectamente (faltaría parsear la columna de fechas a DateTime si es necesario, pero nada más).  La aplicación de `df["resultado"] = df["numeros"] - df["valores"].shift(-1)` (obviamente cambiando el nombre de las columnas, ya que ni `numeros` ni `valores` existen en este DataFrame) tampoco es problema (siempre que no intentes operar con la columna `Fecha` tal como está). ¿Con no me compila que quieres decir exactamente?

Comment: Mra yo le agrego esto: df['resto'] = df['tiempo5'] - df['anochecer'].shift(-1); print(df)

Comment: La columna `anochecer` no existe es `Anochecer`, la mayúscula inicial. Pandas y Python son sensibles a mayúsculas, por lo que debes tener cuidado con ello siempre. Es decir, debe ser `df['resto'] = df['tiempo5'] - df['Anochecer'].shift(-1)`, de lo contrario debes recibir un `KeyError: 'anochecer'`

Comment: y me aparece un error

Comment: Si era correcto, gracias

Comment: Existe una forma de seleccionar filas y columnas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para poder manipular un dataframe en pandas puedes optar por usar loc

df.loc[ `<ROWS RANGE>` , `<COLUMNS RANGE>`]

Selecciona las columnas y filas especificadas del DataFrame dado.
ROWS O COLUMN RANGE también puede ser ':' y si se da en filas o columnas, entonces todas las entradas se incluirán para la fila o columna correspondiente.

Por otro lado, recuerda los nombres de columna para los marcos de datos distinguen entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, por lo tanto

```
df['resto'] = df['tiempo5'] - df['Anochecer'].shift(-1) //funciona a la perfeccion
```

Cuando quieres cargar un csv o txt, deberas especificar el delitmitador, muchas veces suele traer problemas, te dejo algunos ejemplos

```
def main():

print(' *** Using pandas.read_csv() with Custom delimiter ***')

# Read a csv file to a dataframe with custom delimiter
usersDf =  pd.read_csv('users_3.csv', sep='__'  , engine='python')

print('Contents of Dataframe : ')
print(usersDf)

print('********')

print(' *** Using pandas.read_csv() with space or tab as delimiters ***')

# Read a csv file to a dataframe with delimiter as space or tab
usersDf =  pd.read_csv('users_4.csv',  sep='\s+', engine='python')

print('Contents of Dataframe : ')
print(usersDf)


print(' *** Using pandas.read_csv() with multiple char delimiters ***')

# Read a csv file to a dataframe with multiple delimiters in regular expression
usersDf =  pd.read_csv('users_5.csv',  sep='[:,|_]', engine='python')

print('Contents of Dataframe : ')
print(usersDf)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```